# JavaScript not working under php tag

Tags: javascript, html

Why is Javascript not working in the following line?

```
<?php
echo "<a href='admin-advertiser-delete.php?supplier=$row[adv_id]' onclick='if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>";
?>
```

Comment: Quotes. `onclick=\"if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;\">`

Comment: Or better: `onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\">`

Comment: Do you have that code?

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen That's a browser built-in method.

Comment: ow didn't know that thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes need to be escaped

1. `onclick=\"if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;\"`
2. better `onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\"`
3. MUCH better: NEVER have a GET link delete things since one visist from google bot will kill your database

`echo "<a href='javascriptneeded.html' onclick=\"if (confirm('Are you sure?')
location = 'admin-advertiser-delete.php?supplier=$row[adv_id]';
return false;\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>";`

4. BEST:

---

```
echo "<a href='javascriptneeded.html' class='deleteAdv' data-id='$row[adv_id]'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>";
```

using

```
document.querySelectorAll(".deleteAdv").forEach(function(link) {
  link.onclick=function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure") {
      location = "admin-advertiser-delete.php?supplier="+encodeURIComponent(this.getAttribute("data-id"));
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Please see update - option 4 is the recommended method

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping your quotes. In this part:

```
onclick='if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;'
```

The html parser sees the ' before "*are you sure*" as the ending quote, therefore interpreting it as this:

```
onclick='if (!confirm('
```

Therefore you should escape your quotes and it should work:

```
 onclick='if (!confirm(\'Are you sure?\')) return false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use HEREDOC syntax to get rid ot the problem of escaping quotes:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOD
<a href='admin-advertiser-delete.php?supplier={$row[adv_id]}' onclick='if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) return false;'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>
EOD;
?>
```

See link for documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Note that you won't need to escape quotes but you'll need to use the correct ones:
`onclick='confirm("Ok?")'` is correct, `onclick='confirm('Ok?')'` isn't.

Hope it helps.